# How far in advance before journey date can train tickets in Myanmar be bought?

Tags: trains, tickets, myanmar

I reached out to travel agency based in Myanmar to  look into reserving train tickets from Yangon to Mandalay, and they came back with this:

> [The request] will be submitted to the ticket issuer a maximum of **one week**
>   ahead of travel, and then tickets are issued up to **three days** ahead of
>   your travel date.

Is it really true that tickets are not available for sale more than a week in advance in Burma?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is more or less correct.  Tickets are available starting 5 days before departure and have to be bought in person.  Travel agencies can act as a proxy to buy on your behalf, but they also have to physically go to the train station to buy your ticket.

I would guess this agency's specification of dates has been simply padded a bit to cover things like holidays, weekends or such that might delay buying or sending tickets.